# Create pandas dataframe from sets of series where there are many repeated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a csv file that I need to summarize in a DataFrame. The new df will be based on a time (LFrame) that increments monotonically, but repeats in the csv since there are several records associated with that time step. Many of these simply repeat, but several csv records are unique and I either sum values or take averages of those... as appropriate to my data.

I can do this with the code below, but it runs very slowly (the csv is 40-50MB). Is there a more efficient way of sampling the records that don't change for each LFrame (you can see them below where I access them via `iloc[0]`)?

```
new_File = pd.DataFrame({"LFrame": pfd_df.LFrame.unique(), 
              "Num_Channels": [ pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].num_signals.sum() for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()],
              "Date_Time": [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf]["Date_Time"].iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()],
              "run_time":  [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].run_time.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()], 
              "az":        [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].az.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()], 
              "el":        [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].el.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()], 
              "distance":  [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].distance.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()], 
              "pass_ID":   [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].pass_ID.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()], 
              "SV_ID":     [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].SV_ID.iloc[0] for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()],
              "PFD":       [pfd_df[pfd_df.LFrame == lf].pfd.sum() * (8.28/90) / (1e-26 * 41667) for lf in pfd_df.LFrame.unique()]
                        })
```

I think all the comprehensions are slowing me down significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html). Try something like:

```
funcs = {
    'Num_Channels': ('num_signals', 'sum'),
    'Date_Time': ('Date_Time', 'first'), 
    'run_time': ('run_time', 'first'),
    'az':       ('az', 'first'),
    ...
    'pfd': ('pfd', lambda x: x.sum() * (8.28/90) / (1e-26 * 41667))
}

new_File = pfd_df.groupby('LFrame').agg(**funcs)
```

Comment: I think that's exactly it! I'll try in a bit here and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hum... I guess I don't know how this works since it's saying: `SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'num_signals'` even tho pfd_df has the col.

Comment: I don't know what that means? Remove 'LFrame'? That doesn't work either... However I got it to work with NamedAgg.

Comment: @earnric. My bad!!! I made a mistake. I forgot `**funcs` (same as NamedAgg)

Comment: ok, let me try that... `**funcs`

Comment: that seems to work! Thx 
`funcs = {
    'Num_Channels': ('num_signals', 'sum'),
    'Date_Time': ('Date_Time', 'first'), 
    'run_time': ('run_time', 'first'),
    'PFD': ('pfd', lambda x: x.sum() * (8.28/90) / (1e-26 * 41667))
}

pfd_df_new = all_pfd_data.groupby('LFrame').agg(**funcs)`